# C programming conflicting types/unable to call function

Tags: c

Below is a the code I have written so far for a class project.  I am having a couple of problems that I can not figure out.  The first problem is that the on the following lines I keep getting an error of conflicting types.

```
    int sortsize(struct sampleInfo);
    int newSortsize = sortsize(struct sampleInfo);
```

and

```
    int sortid(struct sampleInfo);
    int newSortid = sortid(struct sampleInfo);
```

I can not seem to figure out what is wrong.  The second problem I am having stems from the first in that I am not able to call these functions to print off the arrays of structure that I need too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
struct sampleInfo
{
  char sample;
  int id;
  int size;
  double value;
} sample[15];
struct sampleInfo id() //int
{
  sample[0].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[1].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[2].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[3].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[4].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[5].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[6].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[7].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[8].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[9].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[10].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[11].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[12].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[13].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
  sample[14].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
}
struct sampleInfo size() //int
{
  sample[0].size = 1;
  sample[1].size = 2;
  sample[2].size = 3;
  sample[3].size = 4;
  sample[4].size = 5;
  sample[5].size = 6;
  sample[6].size = 7;
  sample[7].size = 8;
  sample[8].size = 9;
  sample[9].size = 10;
  sample[10].size = 11;
  sample[11].size = 12;
  sample[12].size = 13;
  sample[13].size = 14;
  sample[14].size = 15;
}
struct sampleInfo value() //double
{
  sample[0].value = 1.000000;
  sample[1].value = 2.000000;
  sample[2].value = 3.000000;
  sample[3].value = 4.000000;
  sample[4].value = 5.000000;
  sample[5].value = 6.000000;
  sample[6].value = 7.000000;
  sample[7].value = 8.000000;
  sample[8].value = 9.000000;
  sample[9].value = 10.000000;
  sample[10].value = 11.000000;
  sample[11].value = 12.000000;
  sample[12].value = 13.000000;
  sample[13].value = 14.000000;
  sample[14].value = 15.000000;
}
struct sampleInfo stringvalue() //char
{
  strcpy(sample[0].sample, "one");
  strcpy(sample[1].sample, "two");
  strcpy(sample[2].sample, "three");
  strcpy(sample[3].sample, "four");
  strcpy(sample[4].sample, "five");
  strcpy(sample[5].sample, "six");
  strcpy(sample[6].sample, "seven");
  strcpy(sample[7].sample, "eight");
  strcpy(sample[8].sample, "nine");
  strcpy(sample[9].sample, "ten");
  strcpy(sample[10].sample, "eleven");
  strcpy(sample[11].sample, "twelve");
  strcpy(sample[12].sample, "thirteen");
  strcpy(sample[13].sample, "fourteen");
  strcpy(sample[14].sample, "fifteen");
}
char userinput()
{
  char choice[4];
  printf("Do you want to sort the samples by id or size?\n");
  scanf("%s",&choice);
  printf("Your choice is %s\n",choice);
  return choice;
}
int sortsize(struct sampleInfo sample[15])
{
  int i;
  int maxsize;
  maxsize = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 14; i++)
  {
    if (sample[i].size >= maxsize)
    {
        maxsize = sample[i].size;
        sample[i++].size;
    }
    else;
  }
  printf("You array sorted by id is %d",&sample[15]);
}
int sortid(struct sampleInfo sample[15])
{
  printf("test");
  int i;
  int maxid;
  maxid = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 14; i++)
  {
    if (sample[i].id >= maxid)
    {
        maxid = sample[i].id;
        sample[i++].id;
    }
    else;
  }
  printf("You array sorted by id is %d",&sample[15]);
}
int main (char choice)
{
  time_t seconds = time(NULL);
  int seed = (unsigned)(seconds);
  srand(seed);
  char userinput();
  char response = userinput();
  if (choice == "id")
  {
    int sortsize(struct sampleInfo);
    int newSortsize = sortsize(struct sampleInfo);
  }
  else
  {
    int sortid(struct sampleInfo);
    int newSortid = sortid(struct sampleInfo);
  }
}
```

Comment: `newSortsize = sortsize(struct sampleInfo);` You are trying to call a function with a variable *type*. You need to pass it a variable of the appropriate type. ie. `newSortsize = sortsize(sample);`

Comment: Your code is beyond repair. Starting from wrong prototype of *main*, to comparing a char to a pointer, and having non-void functions without a return. You have spurious function prototype declarations in *main* that try to redeclare existing functions with conflicting argument types. You're missing includes such as *string.h*. You should start from the beginning by reading some C book, such as "The C Programming Language (2nd edition)".

Answer (score 5):

You have multiple, conflicting declarations for your `sortsize` and `sortid` functions.  You *define* `sortsize` as:

```
int sortsize(struct sampleInfo sample[15]) { ... }
```

which means the function expects an argument which is an *array* of `struct sampleInfo` (technically, it actually expects a pointer, but we won't get into that here).  A function *definition* also serves as a function *declaration*, at least within the same translation unit (source file).

Then, in the body of your `if` statement, you write a new declaration of the function as

```
int sortsize(struct sampleInfo);
```

This second declaration doesn't match the earlier definition - in the first case, the function expects to receive a pointer to `struct sampleInfo`, while in the second expects a single value of type `struct sampleInfo`.  You've confused the compiler.

Since you already have a *declaration* of the function in scope by virtue of defining it earlier, you can drop that second declaration completely.

However, now you have a new problem - your function *call* is written as

```
 int newSortsize = sortsize(struct sampleInfo);
```

In a function *call*, you don't specify the type of the argument again; you pass an object of the required type.  Since your function definition expects an *array* of `struct sampleInfo`, you need to pass an *object* of the same type, which in this case is the `sample` array:

```
int newSortSize = sortsize( sample );
```

Here's how the code should read:

```
if ( strcmp( choice, "id" ) == 0 )      // can't compare strings using == operator
{
    int newSortsize = sortsize( sample );
}
else
{
    int newSortid = sortid( sample );
}
```

with the caveat that, as written, this isn't terribly useful.  However, it should get you past that particular error.

You have other fatal problems in your code - `userinput` will trigger at least one compile error (and won't do what you want anyway), `sortid` and `sortsize` don't actually return anything, and your formatting's a *mess*.  You need to take a step back, find a good C reference, and re-think what you're doing.

**EDIT**

Instead of going through your code line by line and pointing out the errors, it's faster just to re-write it.  I don't feel terribly guilty about doing this since you've put in a good faith effort of writing your own code.  This may not be my highest-quality work, but it should at least build and run more or less as you expect it to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SAMPLE_LENGTH 10  // Longest sample string length, not counting
                              // string terminator

/**
 * Define the sampleInfo type; however, do not create an instance
 * at file scope.  Instead, we'll create an instance in the main 
 * function and pass that instance as an argument to all the other
 * functions.
 */
struct sampleInfo
{
  char sample[MAX_SAMPLE_LENGTH + 1];  // Need an array of `char` to store string values
  int id;
  int size;
  double value;
};

/**
 * change `id` to take an array of struct sampleInfo as input,
 * rather than rely on a global variable.  Also, since the function
 * doesn't actually *return* anything, change the return type to void
 */
void id( struct sampleInfo *sample, size_t count ) 
{
  /** 
   * Use a loop to iterate through the array.  Using the % operator
   * isn't the best way to map the result of rand() to a smaller
   * range, but it's good enough for now.
   */
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    sample[i].id = rand() % 100 + 1;
}

/**
 * Same changes as above
 */
void size( struct sampleInfo *sample, size_t count) //int
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    sample[i].size = i + 1;
}

/**
 * Same changes as above
 */
void value( struct sampleInfo *sample, size_t count ) 
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    sample[i].value = i + 1.0;
}

/**
 * This one doesn't work as a loop, but we add a check to make
 * sure our input array is large enough to accept all the 
 * strings, otherwise we print an error and exit.
 */
void stringvalue(struct sampleInfo *sample, size_t count ) 
{
  if ( count < 15 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "SAMPLE ARRAY IS TOO SMALL\n" );
    exit( 0 );
  }
  strcpy(sample[0].sample, "one");
  strcpy(sample[1].sample, "two");
  strcpy(sample[2].sample, "three");
  strcpy(sample[3].sample, "four");
  strcpy(sample[4].sample, "five");
  strcpy(sample[5].sample, "six");
  strcpy(sample[6].sample, "seven");
  strcpy(sample[7].sample, "eight");
  strcpy(sample[8].sample, "nine");
  strcpy(sample[9].sample, "ten");
  strcpy(sample[10].sample, "eleven");
  strcpy(sample[11].sample, "twelve");
  strcpy(sample[12].sample, "thirteen");
  strcpy(sample[13].sample, "fourteen");
  strcpy(sample[14].sample, "fifteen");
}

/**
 * Instead of returning a local array (which doesn't work), we
 * pass our input buffer as an argument to the function.
 */
int userinput( char *choice, size_t bufsize )
{
  printf("Do you want to sort the samples by id or size?\n");
  if ( fgets( choice, bufsize, stdin ) )
  {
    // clear out the newline character, if present
    char *newline = strchr( choice, '\n' );
    if ( newline )
       *newline = 0;
    printf("Your choice is %s\n",choice);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

/**
 * Find *and return* the largest size value.
 */
int sortsize(struct sampleInfo *sample, size_t count )
{
  int i;
  int maxsize = INT_MIN;  // taken from limits.h

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    if (sample[i].size >= maxsize)
    {
        maxsize = sample[i].size;  // there is no need to manually update i;
    }                              // that's handled by the loop control
  }                                // expression.
  return maxsize;
}

/**
 * Same sort of changes as above.
 */
int sortid(struct sampleInfo *sample, size_t count )
{
  printf("test");
  int i;
  int maxid = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    if (sample[i].id >= maxid)
    {
        maxid = sample[i].id;
    }
  }
  return maxid;
}

/**
 * The main function has two forms:
 *
 *    int main( void ) 
 *    int main( int argc, char **argv ) 
 *
 * Use the second form when you pass command line arguments to the program.
 * argc indicates the number of command line arguments (including the command
 * used to start the program) and argv is an array of the argument
 * strings.
 *
 * In this case, we're not using command-line arguments, so we use the first
 * form.  
 */
int main ( void )
{
  /**
   * Create our sample array within the main function and pass it as
   * an argument to the other functions. 
   */
  struct sampleInfo sample[15];  

  /**
   * When we pass an array as an argument to a function it loses its
   * "array-ness", and what the function receives is just a pointer
   * to the first element.  There's no way for the function to know
   * how many elements are in the array from that pointer value alone,
   * so we have to pass that count as a separate argument.  The following
   * is a common trick to determine how many elements are in an array
   * object - we divide the size of the array (in bytes) by the size
   * of a single element of the array (also in bytes).  
   */
  size_t sampleCount = sizeof sampleInfo / sizeof sampleInfo[0];

  srand( time( NULL ) ); 

  /**
   * Initialize the contents of the sample array.  Ideally, these four
   * functions could be consolidated into a single function, but we'll
   * leave it as it is for now.  
   */
  id( sample, sampleCount );
  size( sample, sampleCount );
  value( sample, sampleCount );
  stringValue( sample, sampleCount );

  /**
   * Create a buffer to store our user input; the buffer size needs to
   * be at least one element longer than our longest expected input.  If
   * "size" is your longest expected input, then the buffer needs to
   * be *at least* 5 characters wide.  I'm making it 6 to account for the
   * newline character as well.  
   */
  char response[6];
  if ( !userInput( response, sizeof response ) )
  {
    fprintf( "Error on input...exiting\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  /**
   * You can't use the == operator to compare strings (or any array
   * expressions).  You need to use strcmp here:
   */
  if ( strcmp( choice, "id" ) == 0)
  {
    int newSortsize = sortsize( sample, sampleCount );
    /*
     * do something useful with newSortSize
     */
  }
  else
  {
    int newSortid = sortid( sample, sampleCount );
    /*
     * do something useful with newSortId
     */
  }

  /**
   * As of C99, main doesn't have to actually return a value, 
   * but I think it's a good idea to do so anyway.
   */
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @user3386109: bah - I was fixating on the other stuff.  I'll fix it.

Comment: I think you forgot to dereference the `newline` pointer in `newline = 0;`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä: Thanks.  Fixed.